# MySQL INNER JOIN returns a row but from the front end,it shows no rows

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have this code as my SQL script

```
SELECT 
    lib_use_details.book_code,
    book_details.book_name,
    lib_use_details.date_out,
    lib_use_details.exp_date_in
FROM
    lib_use_details
        INNER JOIN
    book_details ON lib_use_details.book_code = book_details.book_code
WHERE
    lib_use_details.stu_details = 0001
```

When I execute this code directly on the database, it returns a 1 row as shown by this image
[image: showing database result]

However my front-end displays nothing as shown by this
[image: image of the front end]

Why is this result conveyed from the db to the frontend?

This is the code that displays on the front end

```
$querysql = $conn->prepare("SELECT lib_use_details.book_code, `book_details.book_name, lib_use_details.date_out ,lib_use_details.exp_date_in `FROM lib_use_details INNER JOIN book_details ON lib_use_details.book_code` `=book_details.book_code WHERE lib_use_details.stu_details = 0001");



$querysql->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$querysql->execute();
$result=$querysql->fetchAll();

echo '
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Book ID</th>
    <th>Book Title</th>
    <th>Date Borrowed</th>
    <th>Expected Return Date</th>
    <th>Actual Return Date</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
  ';




foreach ($result as $row) {
        $field2= $row['term'];
         $field3=$row['amount'];
        $field4= $row['bal'];
         $field5=$row['mode'];
        $field6= $row['date_received'];
        echo '
        <tbody><tr> 

      <td>'.$field2.'</td>
      <td>'.$field3.'</td>

      <td>'.$field4.'</td>
      <td>'.$field5.'</td>

      <td>'.$field6.'</td> 


  </tr></tbody>
   ';    

  }
  echo ' <tfoot>
  <tr>
      <th>Book ID</th>
      <th>Book Title</th>
      <th>Date Borrowed</th>
      <th>Expected Return Date</th>
      <th>Actual Return Date</th>
  </tr>
</tfoot>';
```

Thanks

Comment: There is obliviously error in displaying data, show that part of code. Debugging 1 on 1.

Comment: you have to add also the code that displays your page.

Comment: The name of the row variables were actually off. Thanks for suggesting a review

Comment: Is there any CSS?

Comment: ```lib_use_details.stu_details = 0001``` != ```lib_use_details.stu_details = "0001"```